# php get_headers a good way to tell if a site is up?

Tags: php, get-headers

I'm still fairly new to php, can you comment on whether the code below is any good to tell if a site is up or down and if it might not be suitable the reasons why and better altneratives?

Thanks in advance.

```
$siteHeader = @get_headers($url , 1);
if ($siteHeader > 1) {
    $siteUp = true;
} else {
    $siteUp = false;
}
```

Comment: get_headers Inconsistency : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781795/get-headers-inconsistency

Answer (score 2):

i use curl, but thats just me:

```
function check($url, $ignore = '')
{
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (B*U*S)";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 45);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 45);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5); //follow up to 10 redirections - avoids loops


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); //fix for certificate issue
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); //fix for certificate issue


    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    $codes = array(
        0 => 'Domain Not Found',
        100 => 'Continue',
        101 => 'Switching Protocols',
        200 => 'OK',
        201 => 'Created',
        202 => 'Accepted',
        203 => 'Non-Authoritative Information',
        204 => 'No Content',
        205 => 'Reset Content',
        206 => 'Partial Content',
        300 => 'Multiple Choices',
        301 => 'Moved Permanently',
        302 => 'Found',
        303 => 'See Other',
        304 => 'Not Modified',
        305 => 'Use Proxy',
        307 => 'Temporary Redirect',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        402 => 'Payment Required',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
        406 => 'Not Acceptable',
        407 => 'Proxy Authentication Required',
        408 => 'Request Timeout',
        409 => 'Conflict',
        410 => 'Gone',
        411 => 'Length Required',
        412 => 'Precondition Failed',
        413 => 'Request Entity Too Large',
        414 => 'Request-URI Too Long',
        415 => 'Unsupported Media Type',
        416 => 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
        417 => 'Expectation Failed',
        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
        501 => 'Not Implemented',
        502 => 'Bad Gateway',
        503 => 'Service Unavailable',
        504 => 'Gateway Timeout',
        505 => 'HTTP Version Not Supported'
    );

    $httpcode_out = 'http: ' . $httpcode . ' (' . $codes[$httpcode] . ')';
    $err = 'curl error: ' . $err;

    $out = array(
        $url,
        $httpcode_out,
        $err
    );

    if ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 307)
    {//good
        return array(
            'Work',
            $out
        );
    }
    else
    {//BAD
        return array(
            'Fail',
            $out
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The more I think of it, the less fine it looks. I 've expanded on my initial answer, which in retrospect was naive.

It's fine for *basic* usage, but you might want to check the HTTP response code as well instead of just checking if you got a response. The way the code is right now, it just tells you that there was someone listening on the other side, which is a long way from what most people would consider "the site is up".

Here's how to easily isolate the HTTP response code (or get `false` if the request failed):

```
$headers = get_headers('http://www.google.com');
$code = $headers ? intval(end(explode(' ', $headers[0], 2))) : false;
```

Apart from that, there's also the matter of redirects: what do you do if you see a redirect? The server you queried might be OK, but the server you are redirected to might be down. If someone typed the URL in a browser they 'd be redirected and ultimately time out, while the one-step test would say everything's OK. What if there's a redirect loop? A browser would detect this and eventually time out, but you need to write quite a lot of code to do the same.

So in the end cURL does look like the only surefire solution because it does all this transparently.

Comment: get_headers Inconsistency : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781795/get-headers-inconsistency .. it might not be the best option .. am running similar test on curl now

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your case but, specially if your URL is submitted by an user, I would go for something like that.

```
//returns true, if domain is availible, false if not
function isDomainAvailible($domain)
{
   //check if URL is valid
   if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
           return false;
   }

   $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
   curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
   curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
   $page=curl_exec($ch);
   //echo curl_error($ch);
   $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   curl_close($ch);
   if ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300) 
    return true;
   else 
    return false;
}
```

Mostly because some servers won't respond if you don't send an useragent.

Comment: "Mostly because some servers won't respond if you don't send a useragent." - Is that actually true? Even if it were, curl might be overkill for this. I'd write a solution with just PHP sockets, but I guess this is sufficient anyway.

Comment: @JohnChadwick yest it is. As a secure measure :)