# check if link "still" exists

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I check for valid (not dead) links programatically using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244506/how-do-i-check-for-valid-not-dead-links-programatically-using-php)

I am creating a website with many links to external websites, and these websites may go down.

Is it possible to do something like stress tests once in a while to see if they are "still there" ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244506/how-do-i-check-for-valid-not-dead-links-programatically-using-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843129/php-get-headers-a-good-way-to-tell-if-a-site-is-up might help

Comment: where the down votes necessary ?

Answer (score 3):

This might do

```
function checkLink($link){ 
    flush(); 
    $fp = @fopen($link, "r"); 
    @fclose($fp); 
    if (!$fp){ 
        return "link is not active"; 
    }else{ 
        return "link is active"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: for this allow_url_fopen should be on in the php.ini config?